# Wildcard not working? - JPQL in JPA

Tags: jpa, wildcard

I've got a class MovieElement, a field url which is the id, and an other field name.
Just for testing the values of name and url are the same.
An object is persisted with name & url = "www.test.com"
But I cannot get the wildcard working, I tried a query like:

```
query = em.createQuery("SELECT m FROM MovieElement m WHERE m.name LIKE :keyword");
query.setParameter("keyword", "%test%");
query.getResultList();
```

This gives an empty result.

But the following works:

```
query = em.createQuery("SELECT m FROM MovieElement m WHERE m.name LIKE :keyword");
query.setParameter("keyword", "www.test.com");
query.getResultList();
```

Evenso all the next ones results in a null:

```
MovieElement el = em.find(MovieElement.class, "%test%");

query = em.createQuery("SELECT m FROM MovieElement m WHERE m.name LIKE :keyword");
query.setParameter("keyword", "www.test.co_");
query.getResultList();

query = em.createQuery("SELECT m FROM MovieElement m WHERE m.name LIKE :keyword");
query.setParameter("keyword", "%");
query.getResultList();
```

Due to the last query it seems the code doesn't take the wildcard into account.
Further I'm using DataNucleus and MongoDb.

Anyone an idea? Thx!

Comment: I'd expect that a look at the log would tell you all you need to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution: Seems like Datanucleus for mongodb recognizes ".*" as the wildcard instead of "%"